# Windows 7: forcing any program to use a specific sound card/output?

Tags: windows-7, audio, sound-card, volume-mixer

My laptop has two sound outputs, HDMI and analog/jack. By setting the default sound output to use one output and a program (e.g.: foobar2000) to use the other, I can have music come from my big hifi speakers and notification sounds come from my desktop speakers. Windows also allows one to set an individual volume level for each program.
Not all programs (e.g.: Coolplayer, Google Chrome) have an option to select a preferred sound output, however. Is there any way to force such programs to use a specific output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So far, the closest thing I've found is [Vista Audio Changer](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vachanger/). It doesn't seem to actually allow one to choose an output per program though, but instead can change the *default* output when a program is launched, causing all other programs to play to that output as well.